# How do I access a variable defined in URL when using Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I had a read of the documentation, but couldn't see an example of how it would be possible to use the variable in traditional PHP style of `$_POST['var']`

I'm pretty sure my URL is legit:

`domain.com/module/controller/action/var/value/`

Using the above as an example:

`$var` didn't work

`$_POST['var']` didn't work

How is it done?

Answer (score 4):

As presented in [zend controller's documentation page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) you can retrieve parameters like this:

```
public function userinfoAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $username = $request->getParam('username');

    $username = $this->_getParam('username');
}
```

You should also note that [request documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html) states:

> In order to do some of its work, `getParam()`  actually retrieves from several sources. In order of priority, these include: user parameters set via `setParam()`, `GET` parameters, and finally `POST` parameters. Be aware of this when pulling data via this method.
>
> If you wish to pull only from parameters you set via `setParam()`, use the `getUserParam()`.
>   Additionally, as of 1.5.0, you can lock down which parameter sources will be searched. `setParamSources()` allows you to specify an empty array or an array with one or more of the values '_GET' or '_POST' indicating which parameter sources are allowed (by default, both are allowed); if you wish to restrict access to only '_GET' specify `setParamSources(array('_GET'))`.

Answer (score 2):

`$this->_request->getParam('paramName', $defaultValueToReturnIfParamIsNotSet);`